# Access Tweets via conversation_id with Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Twitter API v2.0 added a [conversation_id](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/conversation-id) which supposedly enables easier access to an entire Twitter thread. Previously this kind of work was done by accessing the original tweet and then keeping track of the `in_reply_to_status_id` field. This is easy for replies to the original tweet, but is more cumbersome for replies to replies.

I suspect I'm missing something simple and appreciate any help. The API documentation says the `conversation_id` will match the `tweet_id` of the tweet which started the original conversation. After applying my tokens, the search code is:

```
replies=[]
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets,q='conversation_id:<1565355188004741120>',timeout=999999).items(1000):
        replies.append(tweet)
```

However, the list replies returns empty. I know that conversation_id is valid because I've access the first level replies via legacy code. Any insight to using the conversation_id field is appreciated. There's surprisingly little information out there on its use. Thank you!

**SOLUTION**
The issue was api v1.0 vs 2.0. The following works:

```
replies=[]
for tweet in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets, query='conversation_id:1565355188004741120'):
        replies.append(tweet)
```

Comment: Might be that you are utilizing `api.search_tweets` since tweepy.API is for Twitter API v1.1. If I were to guess, you'll probably need to use `tweepy.Client.search_recent_tweets` instead: https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.search_all_tweets

Comment: That did it. Thank you, this makes some of my broader confusion clearer as well. Now I just need to figure out parsing the response object.

Comment: Regarding building a rule, see https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/integrate/build-a-rule (Make sure to checkout the table) The new twitter rule strings are also used in various other API v2 functions including StreamingClients